# C# Update Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, crud

I am getting an error could not find a non-generic method 'UpdateRow' that has parameters: id, values, tableName, (then it names all rows eg: ISBN, etc)

So it looks like my var query isn't putting all of the vaules within the values string when updating, and the table name isn't set to the table and the ID isn't set to the id column, so I am unsure what I can do to change this.

```
public bool UpdateRow(Dictionary<string, string> id, Dictionary<string, string> values, string table)
{
    Boolean returnCode = true;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        var query = String.Format("UPDATE {0} SET ({1}) WHERE {1}='{2}", table, id, values);

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    return returnCode;
}
```

Will provide more info if needed. Thank you

:more info

Thanks for your help, I am currently trying to update any row from 3 tables which i select with my previous getAll function, takes unique identifier of the row to be edited as an array of one the value plus the name of the column representing the primary key, an array containing the values indexed by the column names as well as a string representing the table name.

Comment: You use `values`, which is a `List<T>`.  You either need to use `IN` in the query pass in `values` as a comma delimited list (you can use `String.Join` to do that), or pass in a single value from the `values`.

Comment: What is the error you get exactly? You are aware you try to put `Dictionary<string, string>` to your `SET` part, right? Maybe you need to iteration?

Comment: Table name and column name should be constant or use Dynamic SQL: [update-with-column-name-by-parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602773/update-with-column-name-by-parameter)

Comment: "Will provide more info if needed"... well more info is always better. Sounds like you're attempting to call `Update()` when your method name is `UpdateRow()`.

Comment: Thanks I ran it agian with the new name now it says updaterow, okay Tim that makes sense do you mind showing me an example of this please?  the error is could not find a non-generic method 'UpdateRow' that has parameters, which is due to the var query line not working as desired/being wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is in building your SQL update statement, your SQL is incorrect and you're trying to update multiple columns but pass in a dictionary (it won't do the work for you).

```
var query = String.Format("UPDATE {0} SET ({1}) WHERE {1}='{2}", table, id, values);
```

I would suggest getting your SQL statement working first.  Something like...

```
UPDATE TableName
SET col1 = 5, col2 = 3 
WHERE ID = 7
```

Once you have that, then focus on building the query in c#...

```
var query = new StringBuilder();
query.AppendFormat("UPDATE {0}\r\n", table);
query.Append("SET \r\n");
// for each col in dictionary {
  query.AppendFormat(" {0} = '{1}',\r\n", col.Key, col.Value);
// }
query.AppendFormat("WHERE Id = '{0}'\r\n", id);
```

The above is just to give you an idea.  It won't work copy and paste (you'll have to do some work on it).

My assumption is that you just want to update one row (so id is of type string rather than dictionary)?  But you could change it to multiple rows if that is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I am currently trying to update any row from 3 tables which i select with my previous getAll function, takes  unique identifier of the row to be edited as an array of one the value plus the name of the column representing the primary key, an array containing the values indexed by the column names as well as a string representing the table name.

Comment: That's a lot of information you have missed out of the question.  I suggest you update the question with that plus table names and columns so people have a better idea what you are after.

Comment: You could always iterate over the keys in ID dictionary and for each one call a separate method to update a single table/id (pass in id of type string).

Comment: thanks, okay that sounds a great idea, although how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your string is using the dictionaries as values rather than the strings they contain. If you really want to pass an entire dictionary, you will have to search for the string you are trying to find.

**Getting the Value**

```
string idString;
bool isValidArgument = id.TryGetValue("KeyOfString", out idString);

if (isValidArgument)
{
    // Code here
}
else
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ID key.");
```

I would suggest passing just the string in your method.