# Insert column name at runtime in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do I dynamically change value of column when inserting data into database?
@itemName doesnt work for me.

```
private void checkedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
  {
      int itemIndex = e.Index;
      string itemName = checkedListBox.Items[itemIndex].ToString();
      string connectionString = "...";


      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      con.Open();

      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Daily(@itemName) values (1)", con);

      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
  }
```

Comment: This problem has been explained a lot. You cannot use parameters to represent columns or table names.

Comment: So what do I do then? My goal is to update database of certain column every time user checks item box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update with column name by parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602773/update-with-column-name-by-parameter)

Comment: If your columns names are not typed from your user and you are absolutely certain that none can tamper with that name you can use string concatenation for this specific context. Otherwise there is Dynamic Sql. Here some samples https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/